# Patch custom object with kubernetes javascrtip SDK

Tags: javascript, kubernetes

I'm using [External Secrets](https://external-secrets.io/v0.6.0-rc1/) to sync my secrets from azure.  And now I need a programmatic way to trigger the sync.  With `kubectl` the command is

```bash
kubectl annotate es my-es force-sync=$(date +%s) --overwrite
```

So, I try to use k8s js sdk to do this.  I can success fully get the External Secret

```js
await crdApi.getNamespacedCustomObject("external-secrets.io", "v1beta1", "default", "externalsecrets", "my-es")
```

However, when I try to update it with `patchNamespacedCustomObject`, it always tells me `"the body of the request was in an unknown format - accepted media types include: application/json-patch+json, application/merge-patch+json, application/apply-patch+yaml"`

Here's my code

```js
const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig();
kc.loadFromString(kubeConfig);

const crdApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CustomObjectsApi);

let patch = [{
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/metadata/annotations",
    "value": {
        "force-sync": "1663315075"
    }
}];

await crdApi.patchNamespacedCustomObject("external-secrets.io", "v1beta1", "default", "externalsecrets", "my-es", patch);
```

I am referring their patch example [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/examples/patch-example.js)

Comment: Don't worry.  Just figured it out, `const options = { "headers": { "Content-type": k8s.PatchUtils.PATCH_FORMAT_JSON_PATCH}}; ` is still required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
const options = {
  "headers": {
    "Content-type": k8s.PatchUtils.PATCH_FORMAT_JSON_PATCH
  }
};
```

is still required.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.